# Upper bound for doubly exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series, for $k_0 \geq 1$ and $a>1$,
$$
S_{k_0} := \sum_{k=k_0}^\infty e^{-a^k}.
$$
We clearly have $S_{k_0} \geq e^{-a^{k_0}}$, however it also feels like we should have $S_{k_0} \leq C(a, k_0) e^{-a^{k_0}}$, for some $C(a, k_0) <\infty$. (In fact, we do, since we can simply divide the summation by $e^{-a^{k_0}}$ to obtain such a constant.)

However, I am wondering if it is possible to give some sort of "simple" upper bound on $C(a, k_0)$. What is its rough order/dependence on $a, k_0$?

Comment: A crude estimate is $$
S_{k_0 }  = e^{ - a^{k_0 } } \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {e^{ - a^{k_0 } (a^n  - 1)} }  \le e^{ - a^{k_0 } } \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + a^{k_0 } (a^n  - 1)}}}  \le e^{ - a^{k_0 } } \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{a^n }}}  = e^{ - a^{k_0 } } \frac{a}{{a - 1}}
$$ which is acceptable if $a$ is not too close to $1$.